# How can I detect web pages completely?

Tags: redirect

A few months back I had changed the url structure of my webpages as follows:

**Old** : www.xyz.com/productname.php?id=XYZ

**New** : www.xyz.com/product/XYZ

But at the same time, the url structure of some of the other pages which are not associated with productname.php page has been created.

e.g. `www.xyz.com/product/about-us.php` has been created for page  `www.xyz.com/about-us.php`  and that new page sends the user to 404 error page.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your architecture. 
Is `xyz.com` a static website?

Are you using a webserver like `nginx`? If yes, you can easily add a redirection rule by referring to https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

If your website is being maintained by a third party, then the only way to fix this issue is to contact them.

Comment: The pages are dynamic and I think you didn't get the issue properly. The URL redirection rule is working properly but has created some unnecessary broken links.